# Cannot instantiate class: "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory" since moved from jdk8 to jdk11

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ldap, classloader

I have a Spring Boot (v2.4.5) web application that is using (in one of the Service classes) an LDAP search if user detail data.
This search worked while we were using JDK8 but once we transitioned to JDK11, this feature is broken.
The relevant parts of the stack trace:

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory" [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"]
        at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getFactory(Unknown Source)
        at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.lambda$getInitialContext$1(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.AbstractClassLoaderValue$Memoizer.get(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.AbstractClassLoaderValue.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source)
        at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
        at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
        at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source)
        at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.naming/javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.loadClass(TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.java:72)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1187)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at java.naming/com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.naming/com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.naming/com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

The setup of the LDAP part is standard:

```
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INITCTX);
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, HOST);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, LDAP_USERNAME + DOMAIN);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, LDAP_PASSWORD);

DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
```

The error happens in the line above.

Searched extensively the SO archives and it seemed to me that the java.naming module is not exporting anymore the ldap package content so followed the advice (from the java migration guide and from SO articles) and added --add-exports java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap=ALL-UNNAMED command line arguments. This did not help.
The Classloader that's active in the thread is
`Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader@148 "TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader"`
What else should I try?